# JavaScript - How to call a method of a imported JS file

Tags: javascript

How to define a method 'foo' in a javascript file 'test.js' so that I can import that file into another javascript file and call the method 'foo'?

Answer (score 1):

Before going further you'll need to figure out what kind of modules you're using, there're 2 common types of modules that I know CommonJS and ES

In either type of module you're using, in order for you to import your method, you will need to export it as a module first.

The details of their differences are found in the NodeJS document [NodeJS Import](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#differences-between-es-modules-and-commonjs)

For the ES modules you can export your method 'foo' like this:

```
// normal function
export function foo1() {}

// arrow function
export const foo2 = () => {}

// or this grouping style that I prefer would look more elegant
function foo1() {}
const foo2 = () => {}
// we can export multiple methods at once
export {
 foo1,
 foo2
}
```

On the other hand, using the CommonJS module, you can export your method 'foo' like this:

```
// a single method
module.exports.foo1 = function() {}
module.exports = function foo2() {}

// multiple methods
module.exports = {
 foo1: () => {},
 foo2: () => {}
}
```

Once you've exported your methods as modules, you can now import them like this:

```
import { foo1, foo2 } from './test.js'
const exec = foo1();

or

import * as test from './test.js'
const exec = test.foo2();
```

Hope this help